# How can I change the Graph required data such as EdgeWeight, VertexWeight, EdgeCapacity, VertexCapacity in the Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I asked this question in different form and because I couldn't receive the proper answer so I have to change my question.I know that was my fault sorry. I need to change the Matrix Data of nodes and edges in the graph. How can I do that on the graph itself by clicking on each node?

```
Graph[{"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", 
  "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
  "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, 
 EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{10, 100}, 14] 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: What is Matrix Data?

Comment: You can't do it by clicking on each node.  You need to enter commands to set these properties.  The command to look up is `SetProperty`.

Comment: Can you clarify if your question is about how to set the weights, or about how to set the weights using a graphical point-and-click interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use to set properties on graphs is `SetProperty`.  Sometimes this function can be a bit inconsistent and difficult to figure out, but this time the standard syntax works:

```
SetProperty[{g, "Uppsala" \[DirectedEdge] "Marsta"}, EdgeWeight -> 15]
```

You could also use

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeWeight -> {"Uppsala" \[DirectedEdge] "Marsta" -> 20}]
```

Note the use of `\[DirectedEdge]` instead of `->`.  You can enter it using <kbd>esc</kbd> `de` <kbd>esc</kbd>.  Also note that `SetProperty` does not change the graph `g`.  It simply return a new graph with the selected property changed.  If you need to change the graph, use `g = SetProperty[g, ...]`.

Comment: How can I change on the graph not in the coding?I mean in an interactive just by clicking?

Comment: @Alex I am not aware of any solution for that *in Mathematica*.  You'd have to write one.  You can use some other program (Gephi?  Cytoscape?  not sure if they can do this), construct the graph, export it to GraphML or a similar format, then import it to Mathematica.