# How can I assign EdgeCost for the graph edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

Here is my code:

```
g = Graph[{Property["Uppsala" -> "Marsta", EdgeCost -> 20], 
   "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", 
   "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", 
   "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", "Stockholm" -> "Boo", 
   "Boo" -> "Stockholm", "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", 
   "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", 
   "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", "Stockholm" -> "Taby", 
   "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeWeight -> {10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 70, 80, 46, 87, 98, 90, 14, 19, 
    101}]
test = FindMinimumCostFlow[g, "Uppsala", "Taby", "OptimumFlowData"]
test["CostValue"]
Text[Grid[{#, test[#]} & /@ test["EdgeList"], 
  Background -> {None, {{White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {{Center, Right}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{17, 6}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], ItemStyle -> 14, 
  Spacings -> {Automatic, .8}]]
```

Why I still have the cost value of 5 when I specified the `EdgeCost` to be 20 for my first edge?

Comment: The documentation for `Edgecost` suggests `EdgeCost->{value1, value2, ... valueN}` Does this not work as you wish?

Comment: Alex, I don't really see how this is different from your previous (two) [questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25124/how-can-i-change-the-graph-required-data-such-as-edgeweight-vertexweight-edgecap)  If the answer there did not help, why don't you comment there and ask for clarifications?

Comment: @bill s Sorry no it wont work.Could you please where it has to be stated?I need to use  `FindMinimumCostFlow` as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs no it is different question.Actually this time I want to assign costs in the coding for my edges and have difficulty with that.

Comment: @Alex Please show us what you have tried so far and what exactly you mean by "it did not work".  The answer here is the same as to your last question. You assign an EdgeCost the same way as you assign an EdgeWeight.

Comment: @Szabolcs the last questions was about how can have the code which create interactive graphs where I have to be able to change VertexWeight for example on the graph itself not in the code by just clicking.This question is about how can I assign EdgeCost in my coding.OK?

Comment: The answer to that is given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25128/12), i.e. the answer to your last question.  *Have you tried it?*

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to use the FindMinimumCostFlow commnad and I want to have it in my "CostValue".But even after setting your mentioned SetProperty command I still have the default 1 for each EdgeCost.It is about EdgeCost not EdgeWeight .That is new in Mathematica 9.

Comment: Alex, read your question again, and imagine that you are someone who knows nothing about your problem.  What would you reply?  First you asked how to assign EdgeCost values, even though you already had the answer for that.  Then you asked why `FindMinimumCostFlow` does not give you the answer you expect (which is a different question), but you did not tell us how you used it, what you got as a result, and what you expected as a result.  Could you yourself answer a question put like this?  Do you see my point?

Comment: @Szabolcs here is the problem again.Do I need to change the question as well?